# HTTP Request failed in IONIC for latest android

Tags: http, ionic3

IONIC 3
I am getting "Request failed" error when I am sending POST request to server.
This issue only comes on latest android devices.
I have set all necessary headers in my server already.
Please check attachment for more details.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably one reason is that you are using `http` not `https`

set `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` in `AndroidManifest.xml` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest ...>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application
        ...
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        ...>
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```